Stop org-cycle from prompting for header-args
When in an org-mode buffer inside a code block, normally tab invokes indent-for-tab.
(I have org-cycle-emulate-tab set to t.)
However, if point is after a colon, Emacs prompts me for a header-arg.
I'm a long-standing user of org-mode, but I don't recall ever seeing this behavior until quite recently. Am I going crazy, or is this a recent change to org-mode?
In any case, I find the behavior highly intrusive, especially when programming in languages like Python that use a lot of colons. Does anyone know how to disable this?

I can reproduce this (and I don't remember ever running into it, but maybe I never pressed a TAB after a colon in a code block...). It's worth at least a bug report to the Org mode mailing list.

I’m voting to close this question because the problem was caused by a bug that has now been fixed: see https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs/org-mode.git/commit/?id=8b4b89b14b9b177b73bc983faa66bb4fa6f7ad26

I think it's a bug in the function org-babel-header-arg-expand which is not careful enough to make sure that it's on a babel header.
The problem is that this function is part of org-cycle-tab-first-hook. As a temporary work-around, consider deleting it from the hook, by adding something like this to your init file:
(require 'org-cycle)
(with-eval-after-load 'ob-core
   (setq org-cycle-tab-first-hook 
          (delete #'org-babel-header-arg-expand org-cycle-tab-first-hook)))

although this will have repercussions on your ability to tab-expand header args.
A full solution would involve modifying org-babel-header-arg-expand to check whether point is on a header line before proceeding. But that's a matter for the Org mode maintainers: please submit a bug report with M-x org-submit-bug-report.

EDIT: I submitted a bug report (acknowledging you and referencing this question) to the Org mode ML.
UPDATE: I also submitted a patch which has now been merged into the main branch: the commit can be found at https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs/org-mode.git/commit/?id=8b4b89b14b9b177b73bc983faa66bb4fa6f7ad26
